# Meaning of "at which point"

Tags: phrases, syntactic-analysis

I understand that *at which point* is completely grammatical and I know how and when to use it, but it just now struck me as an odd phrase.

What exactly is *which* doing here? How does it make the phrase make sense?

> Example:
>   I ran ten miles without stopping, at which point I felt sick.

I want to think *which* is being used in the usual sense referring to a selection (e.g., *which of these*), but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: "at which point" identifies a point (that is, selects the point).

Comment: @phoog That doesn't tell me much apart from knowing what each word means.

Comment: I'd say it's being used as a determiner. See example sentences [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/which).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Which***  is here used as a ***[determiner](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/which)*** :

> - (followed by a noun): Which colour do you like best?
> - used when someone knows, says, is not certain about etc the specific choice between two or more possibilities.
>
>   - *They’re all so pretty – I don’t know which one to choose.*
>   - *It was either whisky or vodka – I forget which.*
>   - *Did he say which hotel he was staying at?*
>   - *I don’t know which is worse – spending Christmas alone or watching my friends get drunk.*

(macmillandictionary.com)

- *At which point, that is, the point at which*; ***which*** here identifies/determines a *specific point*, among other possible points, at which the action in question is referred to.

Comment: A relative determiner, I might add.